# PowerShell XML Function issue

Tags: xml, powershell, group-policy

I'm trying to recurse through some XML to pull out data, export to a file, and then import into Group Policy.

During each pass, `$DriveObject` and `$UserObject` objects contain the data of the drive map and the user conditions (map drive for this user group, but *not these* users). I'm struggling with inserting the user conditions into `$DriveObject` - error - *Exception calling "Insert" with "2" argument(s): "Insertion index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than or equal to size.
Parameter name: index"* I'm trying to understand why the value is null, and if there is a simpler way of achieving this?

It's based on the script here [Ivanti Environment Manager Configuration: How to export Shortcuts, Drive Mappings and Printer Mappings with Powershell](https://ninaronline.co.uk/2020/12/14/ivanti-environment-manager-configuration-how-to-export-shortcuts-drive-mappings-and-printer-mappings-with-powershell/) but that script doesn't handle conditions.

The XML is an export from Ivanti Environment Manager which we're retiring. An example of some sanitised XML is included in the code.

```powershell
function New-DrivesXML
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [object]$XMLFile

    )

    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$DriveObject = @()
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$UserObject = @()


    # get main group name and operator
    if (($XMLFile.Identifier -eq 'UEM.Condition.UserGroupMembership') -and ($XMLFile.Enabled -eq 'True') -and (($XMLFile.ActionProperties.ActionProperty | where {$_.name -eq "Operator" }).value -eq 'Equal'))
    {
        $GroupName = ($XMLFile.ActionProperties.ActionProperty | where {$_.name -eq "GroupName"} ).value
        if($GroupName -match 'CN=') { $GroupName = ($GroupName).Replace("CN=","").Split(",")[0] }
        $OperatorGroup = ($XMLFile.ActionProperties.ActionProperty | where {$_.name -eq "Operator" }).value 
    }


    # get user name and operator
    if (($XMLFile.Identifier -eq 'UEM.Condition.UserName') -and ($XMLFile.Enabled -eq 'True'))
    {
        $UserName = ($XMLFile.ActionProperties.ActionProperty | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "UserName" }).value
        $OperatorUser = ($XMLFile.ActionProperties.ActionProperty | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Operator" }).value
        
        # get user object and SID, create user XML string
        $ADUserObject = "ADUserObject"
        $ADUserSID = "ADUserSID"
        $UserFilter = "<FilterUser bool=`"AND`" not=`"1`" name=`"$Username`" sid=`"$ADUserSID`"/>"
        
        # add $UserObject to $UserObject
        $UserObject.Add($UserFilter) | Out-Null
    }


    # get drive mapping
    if (($XMLFile.Identifier -eq "UEM.Action.Drive.Map" -and $XMLFile.Enabled -eq 'True'))
    {
        $DriveLetter = ($XMLFile.ActionProperties.ActionProperty | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "DriveLetter" }).value
        $RemotePath = ($XMLFile.ActionProperties.ActionProperty | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "RemotePath" }).value
        
        #Create the $drives string
        $drives = "<Drive clsid=`"{999C9B74-9CB8-4e3c-9999-7DD559B7A899}`" name=`"${DriveLetter}:`" status=`"${DriveLetter}:`" image=`"2`" changed=`"2021-09-07 10:00:00`" uid=`"{B0961CD8-681F-40E8-BBCE-D095A92AB120}`" userContext=`"1`" bypassErrors=`"1`">  
 <Properties action=`"U`" thisDrive=`"SHOW`" allDrives=`"SHOW`" userName=`"`" path=`"$RemotePath`" label=`"`" persistent=`"0`" useLetter=`"1`" letter=`"$DriveLetter`" />  
   <Filters> 
    <FilterGroup bool=`"AND`" not=`"0`" name=`"contoso\$GroupName`" sid=`"$ADGroupSID`"/> 
   </Filters>
</Drive>"

        # Add $drives to $DriveObject 
        $DriveObject.Add($drives) | Out-Null
    }

    
    # Recurse child nodes
    if ($XMLFile.HasChildNodes)
    {
        $ChildNodes = $XMLFile.ChildNodes | Where-Object { $_.NodeType -eq "Element" }
        if ($ChildNodes -ne $null) {
            foreach ($Child in $ChildNodes)
            {
                New-DrivesXML $Child
            }
        }
    }


    # drive mapping is last item in the node
    if ($DriveObject -ne $null) 
    {
        Write-Host "Userobject - $UserObject" -ForegroundColor Red # why is this null/empty?
        
        # Insert userobject into driveobject       
        $DriveObject = $DriveObject.Insert($DriveObject.LastIndexOf('</Filters>'),$UserObject)
    }

    if ($UserObject -ne $null) 
    {
        Write-Host "UserObject - $UserObject" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }


    # return function values #
    $DriveObject

    #### end of main function ####
}


# Load XML
[XML]$XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EMSnippet ClassName="UEM.EMSnippet.0000" CreatedByVerion="101.22.2178.0" OriginConfigFriendlyName="" OriginConfigID="FBDDE2CA-08AA-47AB-A1A0-2B52FA75AFB6">
  <Branches ClassName="UEM.BranchCollection.0000">
    <Branch ClassName="UEM.Branch.0000" OriginalPath="Configuration.User.Events.PostLogon.Branches" VersionNumber="0" LinkID="6E1DD946-F3EB-4520-AC2A-E5CA55E8A24E" OriginalLinkId="DF0235EF-604B-4B89-9CDE-69C72B8F2BE3" OriginID="FBDDE2CA-08AA-47AB-A1A0-2B52FA75AFB6" Name="Drive Mappings" Enabled="True" EventType="UserPostLogOn">
      <Branches ClassName="UEM.BranchCollection.0000">
        <Branch ClassName="UEM.Branch.0000" OriginalPath="Configuration.User.Events.Logon.Branches" VersionNumber="0" LinkID="793B6C92-EF05-44AD-9212-EF506A415F4B" OriginalLinkId="62E461EC-693C-4B9C-BD7D-91BA0AB55760" OriginID="FBDDE2CA-08AA-47AB-A1A0-2B52FA75AFB6" Name="P Drives 1" Enabled="True" EventType="UserPostLogOn">
          <Actions ClassName="UEM.ActionBaseCollection.0000">
            <Action ClassName="UEM.Action.0000" Identifier="UEM.Condition.UserGroupMembership" ActionType="67108864" LinkID="43615E00-2452-436D-987D-106987395823" OriginalLinkId="25516E6B-A531-4D3C-B55E-4D4FB61696A6" OriginID="FBDDE2CA-08AA-47AB-A1A0-2B52FA75AFB6" Name="User Group is Equal to Dept_123. LSA Supported" Enabled="True" StopOnFail="True" IsCached="On" EventType="UserPostLogOn">
              <ActionProperties ClassName="UEM.ActionPropertyCollection.0000">
                <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="Operator" PropertyType="String" Value="Equal" />
                <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="GroupName" PropertyType="String" Value="CN=Dept_123,CN=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com" />
                <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="Query" PropertyType="String" Value="" />
                <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="GroupSID" PropertyType="String" Value="SID" />
              </ActionProperties>
              <Description ClassName="UEM.Description.0000" Text="" />
              <Notes ClassName="UEM.Notes.0000" Text="" />
              <Actions ClassName="UEM.ActionBaseCollection.0000">
                <Action ClassName="UEM.Action.0000" Identifier="UEM.Condition.UserName" ActionType="67108864" LinkID="5114DBD9-66AC-406F-8ED6-E44510CBA64D" OriginalLinkId="CD1DBC7F-6304-4B01-88C4-05922005E74B" OriginID="FBDDE2CA-08AA-47AB-A1A0-2B52FA75AFB6" Name="User Name is Not equal to contoso\user1" Enabled="True" StopOnFail="True" IsCached="On" EventType="UserPostLogOn">
                  <ActionProperties ClassName="UEM.ActionPropertyCollection.0000">
                    <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="MatchCase" PropertyType="Boolean" Value="false" />
                    <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="Operator" PropertyType="String" Value="NotEqual" />
                    <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="UserName" PropertyType="String" Value="contoso\user1" />
                    <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="Query" PropertyType="String" Value="" />
                  </ActionProperties>
                  <Description ClassName="UEM.Description.0000" Text="" />
                  <Notes ClassName="UEM.Notes.0000" Text="" />
                  <Actions ClassName="UEM.ActionBaseCollection.0000">
                    <Action ClassName="UEM.Action.0000" Identifier="UEM.Condition.UserName" ActionType="67108864" VersionNumber="1" LinkID="9F0D231D-A522-4E4A-981B-51318D90184A" OriginalLinkId="DF346C19-CB1B-47F0-8BA5-74DFE6CCDD33" OriginID="FBDDE2CA-08AA-47AB-A1A0-2B52FA75AFB6" Name="User Name is Not equal to contoso\user2" Enabled="True" StopOnFail="True" IsCached="On" EventType="UserPostLogOn">
                      <ActionProperties ClassName="UEM.ActionPropertyCollection.0000">
                        <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="MatchCase" PropertyType="Boolean" Value="false" />
                        <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="Operator" PropertyType="String" Value="NotEqual" />
                        <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="UserName" PropertyType="String" Value="contoso\user2" />
                        <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="Query" PropertyType="String" Value="" />
                      </ActionProperties>
                      <Description ClassName="UEM.Description.0000" Text="" />
                      <Notes ClassName="UEM.Notes.0000" Text="" />
                      <Actions ClassName="UEM.ActionBaseCollection.0000">
                        <Action ClassName="UEM.Action.0000" Identifier="UEM.Action.Drive.Map" ActionType="65536" VersionNumber="2" LinkID="625E0C49-7DE7-4350-8A91-E72CF156EDCF" OriginalLinkId="39BEB120-6737-49DF-B6F9-894098464371" OriginID="FBDDE2CA-08AA-47AB-A1A0-2B52FA75AFB6" Name="Map Drive &gt; P:\ to \\SvrStore01\share01$" Enabled="True" EventType="UserPostLogOn">
                          <ActionProperties ClassName="UEM.ActionPropertyCollection.0000">
                            <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="DriveLetter" PropertyType="String" Value="P" />
                            <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="RemotePath" PropertyType="String" Value="\\SvrStore01\share01$" />
                            <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="UndoAction" PropertyType="Boolean" Value="True" />
                            <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="RunAs" PropertyType="String" Value="CurrentUser" />
                            <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="OverrideExistingMapping" PropertyType="Boolean" Value="True" />
                          </ActionProperties>
                          <Description ClassName="UEM.Description.0000" Text="" />
                          <Notes ClassName="UEM.Notes.0000" Text="" />
                        </Action>
                      </Actions>
                    </Action>
                  </Actions>
                </Action>
              </Actions>
            </Action>
            <Action ClassName="UEM.Action.0000" Identifier="UEM.Condition.UserGroupMembership" ActionType="67108864" LinkID="08426319-1DC1-4578-AA51-F9E790F9A3B8" OriginalLinkId="7B4435D3-54B9-42F8-A104-A73EF9C8714F" OriginID="FBDDE2CA-08AA-47AB-A1A0-2B52FA75AFB6" Name="User Group is Equal to Dept456. LSA Supported" Enabled="True" StopOnFail="True" IsCached="On" EventType="UserPostLogOn">
              <ActionProperties ClassName="UEM.ActionPropertyCollection.0000">
                <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="Operator" PropertyType="String" Value="Equal" />
                <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="GroupName" PropertyType="String" Value="CN=Dept456,CN=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com" />
                <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="Query" PropertyType="String" Value="" />
                <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="GroupSID" PropertyType="String" Value="SID" />
              </ActionProperties>
              <Description ClassName="UEM.Description.0000" Text="" />
              <Notes ClassName="UEM.Notes.0000" Text="" />
              <Actions ClassName="UEM.ActionBaseCollection.0000">
                <Action ClassName="UEM.Action.0000" Identifier="UEM.Condition.UserName" ActionType="67108864" LinkID="B89AE9BE-7028-4259-B37A-E1F2AE3B2712" OriginalLinkId="67A6169E-5726-43A0-ABC9-24E515A9DF08" OriginID="FBDDE2CA-08AA-47AB-A1A0-2B52FA75AFB6" Name="User Name is Not equal to contoso\user3" Enabled="True" StopOnFail="True" IsCached="On" EventType="UserPostLogOn">
                  <ActionProperties ClassName="UEM.ActionPropertyCollection.0000">
                    <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="MatchCase" PropertyType="Boolean" Value="false" />
                    <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="Operator" PropertyType="String" Value="NotEqual" />
                    <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="UserName" PropertyType="String" Value="contoso\user3" />
                    <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="Query" PropertyType="String" Value="" />
                  </ActionProperties>
                  <Description ClassName="UEM.Description.0000" Text="" />
                  <Notes ClassName="UEM.Notes.0000" Text="" />
                  <Actions ClassName="UEM.ActionBaseCollection.0000">
                    <Action ClassName="UEM.Action.0000" Identifier="UEM.Action.Drive.Map" ActionType="65536" LinkID="C7F3C90B-E7F3-48EA-9492-6C918606D8A5" OriginalLinkId="ECBE10B4-2B4F-4EC3-AE3B-36A035810CD9" OriginID="FBDDE2CA-08AA-47AB-A1A0-2B52FA75AFB6" Name="Map Drive &gt; P:\ to \\SvrStore02\Share02$" Enabled="True" EventType="UserPostLogOn">
                      <ActionProperties ClassName="UEM.ActionPropertyCollection.0000">
                        <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="DriveLetter" PropertyType="String" Value="P" />
                        <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="RemotePath" PropertyType="String" Value="\\SvrStore02\Share02$" />
                        <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="UndoAction" PropertyType="Boolean" Value="True" />
                        <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="RunAs" PropertyType="String" Value="CurrentUser" />
                        <ActionProperty ClassName="UEM.ActionProperty.0000" Name="OverrideExistingMapping" PropertyType="Boolean" Value="True" />
                      </ActionProperties>
                      <Description ClassName="UEM.Description.0000" Text="" />
                      <Notes ClassName="UEM.Notes.0000" Text="" />
                    </Action>
                  </Actions>
                </Action>
              </Actions>
            </Action>
          </Actions>
        </Branch>
      </Branches>
    </Branch>
  </Branches>
  <RunAsUserLibrary ClassName="UEM.RunAsUserLibrary.0000" RunAsUserLibraryID="573AF6F5-1266-4CE8-8E2C-C14B4782C98A" />
</EMSnippet>'

# Create an empty array 
$res = @()

# Call the function and pass the variables as required 
$res += New-DrivesXML -XMLFile $XML

# export to file when the script works - just display output for now
$res
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What is `$AddDrives`?  Where is it defined?  By default, it is `$null`, so you cannot call the `.Insert` or `.LastIndexOf` methods.

Comment: Thanks for the spot! $AddDrives was a function that I removed but forgot to clean up the insert method. It was a long week. The error is no longer null, but it still errors.